# Getting events on embedded objects with javascript

Tags: javascript, flash

I'm trying to get events to register when clicking on a flash object, but I can't seem to get it to work.  In the below link, clicking on all the other text fields/buttons registers something, but not for the Flash object. Any ideas?

http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/139980/flash%20events/flash_events.htm

Answer (score 1):

You can catch the events in the flash and then send it to the JS. You can also put a div in front of your flash element (position:absolute) and get the events on this.

edit: I'm not 100% sure I got your issue. If you could be more specific that would help

Comment: Well, I'm specifically trying to get the focus/blur events from the Flash object, which I don't think a div will be able to capture.  I want it so when the user is using the flash app, JS registers focus, and when the user clicks away, blur is called (and all the other normal events as well).

Comment: Did you tried setting an id on the flash element and do $('myflashid').onfocus=function(){} ?